# Picasso Image Caching with Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, image, caching, picasso

I am using picasso inside my recyclerview adapter for loading images from network. I've tested it with 40+ items in my recyclerview and 29 of them have images.

I noticed that upon reaching the end of list, when I scroll back up, some of the images are being reloaded from network instead of cache. Is there any way to prevent reloading the image again from the network? Or perhaps an alternative for reducing network bandwidth usage.

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(HOST + post.getImage_url())
                .resize(1920, 1080)
                .onlyScaleDown()
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .into(holder.ivPostImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(context)
                                .load(HOST + post.getImage_url())
                                .resize(1920, 1080)
                                .onlyScaleDown()
                                .into(holder.ivPostImage);
                    }
                });
```

Above is the code that I use for  caching images loaded from the network.

Comment: 1) What transport are you using? OkHttp? 2) Do these images have caching headers enabled, e.g., Last-Modified, ETag, Cache-Control?

Comment: @Mark, I don't know how to answer your question. I'm quite new to to this, so what you see above is all I I've used for loading the image from network. So I guess that's a no for your 2nd question?

Comment: The use of a disk cache is dependent upon the network side of things. I strongly suggest configuring Picasso to use OkHttp, and logging your network traffic, or using something like Chuck (https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck), Stetho (http://facebook.github.io/stetho/), or advanced profiling in Android Studio 3 to actually see your full HTTP requests and responses. 
Here's a good primer on HTTP caching - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I managed to fix it with the following code.

static final long PICASSO_DISK_CACHE_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 50; 
Downloader downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(context, PICASSO_DISK_CACHE_SIZE);
picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build();

with 50MB cache size.